# Building a Java TreeMap from a sorted list of elements

Tags: java, treemap

I have a text file containing a sorted list of words being my dictionary.

I would like to use a `TreeMap` in order to have *log(n)* as average cost when I have to see if a words belongs to the dictionary or not (that is `containsKey`).

I have read of the Black-Read tree being behind the scenes of the `TreeMap`, so it is self balancing.

My question is: which is the best way to feed the `TreeMap` with the list of words?

I mean: feeding it with a sorted list should be the worst case scenario for a binary tree, because it have to balance almost every other word, haven't it?

The list of words can vary from 7K to 150K in number.

Comment: What would be the value in this `TreeMap`? Sounds like all you need is a `TreeSet` (which, behind he scenes, is just a `TreeMap` where all the values are the same dummy value)

Comment: You are right. A sorted list would "cost" O(n) to feed even without balancing

Comment: Why do you want to use a `TreeMap`? You can simply use an `ArrayList` and `Collections.binarySearch`

Comment: @Mureinik: for what I've said you're perfectly right, good point (I did even not remember of TreeSet). I need the value to be the rules by wich I can have the different inflections from stem.

Comment: @DAle: Good point too. But let's say I just need the TreeMap, my focus is on which would be the best way to feed it starting from a sorted list

Comment: Wouldn't feeding it with a pre-sorted collection defeat the purpose?  I mean you have then run a lesser Big-O algorithm before you even feed it to your TreeMap.

Comment: @jiveturkey: I see your point but I downloaded the list and it is already sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeMap` hides its implementation details, as good OO design prescribes, so to really optimize for your use case will probably be hard.

However, if it is an option to read all items into an array/list before adding them to your `TreeMap`, you can add them "inside out": the middle element of the list will become the root, so add it first, and then recursively add the first half and second half in the same manner. In fact, this is the strategy that the `TreeMap(SortedMap)` constructor follows.

If it is not an option to read all items, I think you have no other option than to simply put your entries to the map consecutively, or write your own tree implementation so that you have more control over how to generate it. If you at least know the number of items beforehand, you should be able to generate a balanced tree without ever having to rebalance.

If you do not need the extra features of a `TreeMap`, you might also consider using a `HashMap`, which (given a good hash function for your keys) even has O(1) access.

Comment: Well I actually have to read them all to put them into the tree, so the overhead would be "only" an Array of size n/2 to do the trick (do the 1st half then add and do the second with the same array), I like it.
As for the HashMap, does a good enough hash function actually exists for generic strings?